# i retrived data from array.xml and when i set in grid view it doesn't comes.i m using custom adapter for that

Tags: java, adapter

This is my adapter class.i retrieved data from array.xml and whenever i set in grid view it doesn't comes.i am using custom adapter for that

```java
public class SlokaAdapter extends BaseAdapter
  {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] web;
    //private final int[] Imageid;
    public SlokaAdapter(Context context, String[] web) {
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            //grid = new View(context);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_slokalist, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_sloka);

        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
  }
```

and this is my code in program and it throws same problem as above

```java
public class Slokaa  extends Activity {
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shlokalist);
    GridView gridView1=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_viewStyle);

 final String[] testArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Chapter1homelist);

        final String[]           testArray2=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Chapter2homelist);

 if(chNo.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter 1")){

            gridView1.setAdapter( new SlokaAdapter(this, testArray2));
            String[] chp_names =    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChapterName);
            String tabname1 = chp_names[1];
            txtChapterName.setText(tabname1);


        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please specify your exact problem and post your error message.

Comment: actually i did't get any error but it does't shows data properly in grid view.we are reading data from array.xml. when we are using ArrayAdapter class then it shows correctly.for this we are using custom Adapter class it does't shows properly.

Comment: You never set data to adapter's TextView.